# NS2 tracegraph installation in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line

When I want to run `./trgraph` for ns2 tracegraph I get

```
./trgraph: error while loading shared libraries: libmwsgl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

"tracegraph202linux" http://www.4shared.com/archive/z_iw9icn/tracegraph202linuxtar.html
mglinstaller.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNZV9fQnpIbm1aYU0/view?usp=sharing

```
tar xvf tracegraph202linux.tar.gz
cp mglinstaller.gz tracegraph202/
cd tracegraph202/
gunzip mglinstaller.gz
./mglinstaller

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./bin/glnx86 && ./trgraph
```

... and the tracegraph GUI will open.