# How to install tracegraph into ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, 12.10, libraries, compatibility, segmentation-fault

tracegraph202 is a very old and obsolete tool and is incompatible to Linux still my University thought that it was a good idea to ask the students to install that. I tried installing that from [here](https://ns-2.blogspot.com/2008/10/trace-graph-network-simulator-ns-2.html), [here](https://www.nsnam.com/2013/10/tracegraph-installation-in-ubuntu-1310.html) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897369/ns2-tracegraph-installation-in-ubuntu-16-04) none works in my end. Please help

Comment: When in doubt, grab an old ISO and build a VM around Ubuntu 8.04. Just be advised that it will be difficult to track down *working* repositories for some of the older code.

Comment: The solution maybe provided faster if you share the installation package of tracegraph (tracegraph202.linux.tar.gz or whatever).

Comment: hey I installed the binary from *[here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsnam/)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still possible by executing the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxt6:i386
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -y ./multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb
wget -c http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxp/libxp6_1.0.2-2_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install -y ./libxp6_1.0.2-2_i386.deb

wget -c https://lahore.comsats.edu.pk/research/groups/CNRC/tracegraph202linux.tar.gz
tar -zxvf tracegraph202linux.tar.gz
cd tracegraph202
wget -c https://lahore.comsats.edu.pk/research/groups/CNRC/mglinstaller.gz
gunzip mglinstaller.gz
chmod +x mglinstaller
./mglinstaller
```

Then add the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable to your `~/.bashrc` file by

```
echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/$USER/Downloads/tracegraph202/bin/glnx86" >> ~/.bashrc
```

then

```
source ~/.bashrc
./trgraph
```

This will give the following output:

> ```
> $ ./trgraph Copyright (c) 2001-2005 by Jaroslaw Malek All rights
> reserved. Author contact: wido@o2.pl
>
> Using and copying any version of Trace graph program and its
> documentation is allowed only for non-commercial purposes provided
> that the above copyright  notice and this permission appear in all
> copies and any materials related to Trace graph. Commercial use
> requires a permission from Jaroslaw Malek. Trace graph cannot be
> distributed, sold,  copied or modified without Jaroslaw Malek's
> permission. Trace graph is provided with no warranty. Jaroslaw Malek
> is not responsible  for any events and results caused by using Trace
> ```

and graphical window of the application.

---

Note: binary distribution was found on https://lahore.comsats.edu.pk/research/groups/CNRC/QuickLinks.aspx .

Comment: Thank you, kind sir, for explaining this. I am getting the same error that you got. What should be the solution to that?

Comment: You have to dig deeper on this topic, I have not used this application before.

Comment: I changed the answer a bit as I got the solution. If you check if that works for you too. So that I know that it woks for all.

Comment: Tested the method and adapted it to be better reproducible.